# file upload to rabbitmq

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, asp.net-core-webapi

I need a .NET Api endpoint where I can post a file to a RabbitMQ via streaming. I've done a endpoint to post a file to a server bevore like this: [microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2#uploading-large-files-with-streaming). I know in approximately how I pas data to RabbitMQ:

```
var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my message");
channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: "hello", basicProperties: null, body: body);
```

**But I have no idea how I get the file or the stream into channel.** Is there a tutorial or can you explain it to me? Would be great. Thanks.

Comment: How large of a file are we talking?

Comment: On your sample body is some binary data. It seems you only need to open your file as binary and put it in the publish as body, Then when you subscribe you get like a message.

Comment: You can send byte array, so read content of file as byte array as send it. Pls note that sending file as message would not be a great idea. You can put the file on a common share folder or on something else and publish it's name/location to RabbitMQ queue.

Comment: Agree, It is not a good idea to send a file through Rabbitmq

Comment: I guess the content of the (xml) files is short.

Answer (score 1):

Just read bytes from file:

```
var body = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\test.xml");
channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: "hello", basicProperties: null, body: body);
```

**UPD**
Get uploaded file with `MultipartMemoryStreamProvider` class:

```
    [HttpPost]    
    public async Task Upload()
    {
            var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            var file = provider.Contents.FirstOrDefault();

            var body = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            channel.BasicPublish(
                exchange: "", 
                routingKey: "hello", 
                basicProperties: null, 
                body: body);
   }
```

Comment: But I don't have a file location, I have a stream or at first a POST Api endpoint...?! [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody] string value)
        {...

And than could create a stream from it. So how can I get the incomming file into the body to hand over to RabbitMQ?

Comment: Your question is how to get stream of uploaded file in POST method? Right?

`[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody] string value)`
`{`
`//get stream or bytes[] here`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

If the file being uploaded is small and fits in memory, you can do smth. like:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(new byte[file.Length]);
  await file.CopyToAsync(ms);

  //here you can send these bytes as a message to Rabbit
  Model.BasicPublish(
    exchangeName,
    routingKey,
    body: ms.ToArray());

  return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Hi Max, your code looks good, But when I try aupload via Postman the object file is allways null. I use POST https://localhost:5001/api/FileUpload Body: form-data value: file